# Curl not downloading XML file as expected

Tags: url, batch-file, curl

When adding a URL into a web browser, I get the usual prompt to open the XML file and view it. However, when I use the same URL within a Curl batch file it only appears to download the login aspx page.

```
//stuff/stuff/Report.aspx?Report=All_Nodes_IP_Report&DataFormat=XML&AccountID=<UID>&Password=<password>
```

My batch file looks like this:

```
curl -L "//stuff/stuff/Report.aspx?Report=All_Nodes_IP_Report&DataFormat=XML&AccountID=<UID>&Password=<Password>" -o "local.xml" -v

pause
```

What am I doing wrong? There's no proxy server between me and the report URL..? The web site is https but I can't include that as the validation checker keeps moaning at me :)

Comment: try to record all browser requests and made them to curl reqs. You can use google chrome tools to do it -> https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: check this `save as curl` thing.

Answer (score 0):

why use CURL when you can use one application called `MGET` that i create.

Download Link:
http://bit.ly/1i1FpGE

Syntax of the command:

```
MGET //stuff/stuff/Report.aspx?Report=All_Nodes_IP_Report&DataFormat=XML&AccountID=<UID>&Password=<Password> local.xml
```

And if you want to use HTTPS do it, for best experience use HTTP